# Rescan wired network

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

How can I rescan the wired network? I have found several articles on rescanning the wifi, but so far, none the Ethernet.

Often when working with my dd-wrt router it needs a reboot and a lot of times in Ubuntu 14.04, will not connect again after the router reboot si complete. I then have to reboot Ubuntu to get it to find the router.

**Please note:** The changes I am making to the router, never change any of the addressing things like IP etc and it should connect again. Sometimes it does and sometimes it does not. I think a rescan of the eth0 (or whatever) should solve this without rebooting 14.04. Yes?

Is there an Ethernet equivalent of the following wifi rescan that would solve this?

*sudo iwlist wlan0 scan*

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent of wifi rescan that I know of, because of the nature of the ethernet interface, it's design to auto detect when a cable is connected to the interface. My suggestion is that when you reboot your router, if you have trouble reconnecting afterwards, reboot the network manager (`sudo service network-manager restart`) in lieu of a full system reboot. Once network manager is restarted, it should automatically pickup on the ethernet connection.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds exactly what I am trying to achieve.  I don't mess with the router all that often, but it is a pain to have to reboot 14.04 just for that.

Comment: No problem. If this works for you, please up vote, and mark it as the accepted answer